# How to change the window title of private browsing option in Firefox

Tags: browser, firefox

How to change the window title of private browsing option in Firefox? When I use the private browsing option it shows up in the title as Private Browsing, is there a mechanism to prevent not showing that information, but still be in private browsing mode.

```
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Private+Browsing?style_mode=inproduct&as=u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack is to use `F11` to toggle full screen mode, hiding the window title.

Comment: awesome, this should do for now